# Problem with Magento Connect to upgrade (1.9.2.2 to 1.9.3)

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect-manager

Two days ago, I realized Magento **1.9.2.2** update to version **1.9.3** using Magento Connect (Mage_All_Latest). The process was all right until labeled in a certain way and now do not know how to continue it, because when I enter Magento Connect returns the error

> Unable to read the configuration file

. I have backup of the database but not the system.

*The site works perfectly, front-end and back-end.*

Any solution to return to the previous version updating or how to enter Magento Connect solving that problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I did not have that line to edit either so I searched elsewhere. This is what worked for me (I don't know if all of these steps are necessary):

I disabled the cache and flushed magento cache and cache storage.
I changed the name of `/downloader/connect.cfg` to `connect.cfg-old`

I logged out of magento. 
I logged back in and when directly to **Magento Connect/Connection Manager**.

The error is gone, a new `connect.cfg` file was created and it appears to be working now.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackexcahnge, please refrain from answering a question with further questions or suggestions you're having same issue because it helps nobody. Add a comment to the existing question/answer if necessary.

Comment: Hi, this comment was the solution to my problem. I didn't need to step Flush Cache Storage. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just rename the connect.cfg (or delete it in /downloader directory)

Answer (score 0):

Idownloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php around line 377

comment out

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

you will able to connect again ..

then Delete pkginfo/Mage_All_latest.txt and then from magento connect try to upgrade only mage_all_latest only.. It will upgrade everything successfully without any issues.

Comment: Gracias,

Inserté la frase que me indicaste en el archivo Curl.php ya que no estaba en el archivo, igualmente no funcionó.

Comment: `       $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_URL, $uriModified);
        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        /**
         * Use value from CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (available since PHP 5.5)
         *
         * @link http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php
         */

        $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
        $this->getCurlMethodSettings($method, $params, $isAuthorizationRequired);     
        }`

Comment: Thank you,

I inserted the phrase you entered me in the Curl.php file because it was not in the file, also did not work.

Please delete the previous comments, sorry